# Values of passed variables to php function

Tags: php

How do I see all the values passed to a php function ?

I have a custom function which accepts multiple parameters. When I call that  function in a page, I need to see all the values that were passed for each parameter.

```
function buildPromotionalSection( $f, $a,$b){ echo $f;}
```

then call to function:

```
buildPromotionalSection( 'hello', 'world', '876' );
```

Now I want to see the values that were passed.

Comment: Just use echo inside the function

Answer (score 1):

using the func_get_args() you can get all the argument in a function

```
function buildPromotionalSection( $f, $a,$b)
{ 
    echo $f."<br> ";
    foreach(func_get_args() as $arg) {
        echo 'This value was passed :'.$arg."<br>" 
    }
}
buildPromotionalSection( 'hello', 'world', '876' );
```

Comment: Hi Joseph, please describe what your code does to help provide more value to future readers.

Comment: a simple code snippet on how to get the values passed(arguments) to a php function